# Graphics are too slow in my project

Tags: c#, graphics, gdi+

I am developing zoo simulator project. It contains three thing types to draw: a map, animal environments and the animals themselves. The map is too big to fit on screen, player needs to move screen to see other parts of it. I am using a timer to draw. On its tick, it calls `Invalidate()` for the form being drawing on. In `ZooForm_Paint` method, I first draw every thing in the map on `mapBuffer` Bitmap. Since `mapBuffer` is too big to fit on screen, I draw (on screen) the part of `mapBuffer` the player is where.

Unfortunately, it seems that drawing everything in the map (although it may not be viewed) on `mapBuffer` slows the game. Can I draw my evironments and animals without need to draw entire map first?
How?

My code:

```
public void DrawGame(Graphics g, ref Point locationOnMap)
{
this.drawBufferMap();
this.drawMapLocation(g, ref locationOnMap);
}


private void drawBufferMap()
{
    Bitmap buffer = new Bitmap(this.map.Size.Width, this.map.Size.Height);
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(buffer))
    {
        graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(this.map.Picture, new Point()); // draw entire map

        foreach (var item in this.zoo.Environments) // draw all env.
        {
            graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(item.Picture, item.Bounds.Location);
        }
        foreach (var item in this.zoo.ILocatables) // draw all ILocatables
        {
            graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(item.Picture, item.Location);
        }
    }

    if (this.mapBuffer != null)
    {
        this.mapBuffer.Dispose();
    }
    this.mapBuffer = buffer;
}

private void drawMapLocation(Graphics g, ref Point location)
{
    g.DrawImage(this.mapBuffer, new Rectangle(0, 0, viewSize.Width, viewSize.Height),
        new Rectangle(location.X, location.Y, viewSize.Width, viewSize.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
```

Comment: Hi, do begin with I would consider using XNA instead of winforms/gdi. Second: please show us your code - there are overloads to the DrawImage-Method that allows you to draw only part of the image but every answer would be a wild guess.

Comment: The core issue here is that you are using GDI+ to draw game graphics, which can turn out to be highly complex. If C# is your language of preference, I strongly suggest you consider using XNA Framework for game development. Have you tried it yet? Perhaps it will be complicated to learn the framework in the beginning, but once you start using it, it will get much easier. In the end, the effort will be justified. Just a recommendation.

Comment: @Witchunter I have written already a lot of code and classes. It is hard now to turn to your XNA while I haven't tried it before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you are going to get any easy solutions.  I can offer a few tips and opinions:

- You seem to be creating a new `BitMap` every time you paint the screen.  This is definitely not a good idea, as large bitmaps are absolutely huge in terms of memory.  What you probably want to do is create one when your game loads, and then simply clear it and repaint it at every frame.  I think this is probably one of the bigger performance issues you have.
- There are a number of optimisations you could make afterwards.  E.g. you are "rendering" the image that you will end up painting to the screen on the user interface thread.  If the rendering process takes long, this will be noticeable.  Typically this work happens on a background thread, and then the UI thread just checks if it can repaint using the new image.  (I am simplifying things greatly here).
- For graphics intensive applications, WinForms is not a particularly good environment, as others have pointed out.  You will not get any hardware acceleration at all.  Moving to XNA is one option, but if your application is also quite rich in terms of standard WinForms screens and controls, this is probably not an easy option.  Another suggested alternative might be WPF, where you might be able to get away with using transformations to move things around, which *are* hardware accelerated, and are not too dissimilar to a WinForms application (well, you don't need to implement your own buttons, etc).

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: please note that `Bitmap`s can not be cleared. Perhaps you mean `Graphics`, which can not be used this way.

Comment: Well, `Graphics` is not the actual image that you are painting, it simply represents a painting abstraction over some actual surface (in your case, the `Bitmap` itself).  It can certainly be used to clear the `Bitmap`, just like you are using it to paint other images over it (see: `Graphics.Clear`).  Bottom line:  by creating a new Bitmap for each paint, you are allocating an object that is at least a few MB in size, and then discarding it.  This is going to be very slow and cause all sorts of performance issues, quote possible including GC slowness.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel pointed out: creating a new bitmap each time you need to draw your map will decrease performance. Reuse the same bitmap over and over instead.

Creating a bitmap larger that you need is also very bad for performance. If you need it to scroll around, then it's fine. But if you paint a new image each time anyway, then you should just create it exactly the same size you need. Then you can call *Graphics.TranslateTransform* to compensate for the new coordinates so you can leave your existion code unchanged.

This will make it possible for GDI+ to clip your graphics and simply just don't draw things outside your map bitmap - which will speed things up.